# Laravel One to many relation with custom primary key not working

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to implement one to many relation in laravel
My tables have custom primary key name not id

I have set `$primartKey` attribute as well but the relations doesnot seem to work.

```
activities
|act_ID|act_acc_ID|.........

categories
|acc_ID|.......
```

Here are my Models

```
class Adventure extends \Eloquent {


    /**
     * @var string $table the name of the table
     */
    protected $table = 'activities';

    /**
     * @var string $primaryKey the primary key of the table
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'act_ID';

    /**
     * @var bool timestamps updated_at and created_at columns flag
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     *
     */
    public function category(){
        $this->belongsTo('Category','act_acc_ID');
    }
}


class Category extends \Eloquent {

    /**
     * @var string $table the name of the table
     */
    protected $table = 'categories';

    /**
     * @var string $primaryKey the primary key of the table
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'acc_ID';

    /**
     * @var bool timestamps updated_at and created_at columns flag
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function adventures(){
        $this->hasMany('Adventure','act_acc_ID');
    }
}
```

Now when ever i try to access categories from adventure or adventures from categories i get

> Relationship method must return an object of type
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

What am i doing wrong here ??
There are plenty adventures whose category is 15 so i try
I try `Categories::find(15)->adventures` also tried `Categories::find(15)->adventures()`

Answer (score 4):

You didn't use `return` keyword, it should be something like this:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Category','act_acc_ID');
}

public function adventures(){
    return $this->hasMany('Adventure','act_acc_ID');
}
```

Add the `return` keyword in both relationship methods.

Comment: Yes, I believe that because we do silly mistakes (I did myself), you should have took a break and needed to restart after a break with fresh brain. When things go wrong and couldn't find a solution, just take a break, it helps :-)

Comment: I've switched from `CI` and one day I've wasted 3 hours to find out a bug and it was that, my redirect wasn't showing anything on the screen but I found it on the other day, it was that, I didn't use `return` keyword with redirect, it had to be like `return Redirect(...)` instead of `redirect::(...)`. It took some time to change the practice that I used in `CI`. All the best :-)

Answer (score 3):

you have to set this in you Category model

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: Same issue for me. This fixes the issue, thanks.